# Get image changes Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image, graphics, gdi+

I have to transmit an image from client1 (named as server) to client2 (named as client).
Now, the image to be transmit changed all the time, and I want to trasmit only small pieces of the image which include the changes, so client will be able to replace, and by this to save time and traffic.

Q1.Is their any existed article and or algorithm?

I come with the following Idea, but need help:

- save the last images sent
- Each time the image changed, do XOR between saved and new one, then send the changes

Q2. Is their are any fast/existed API in windows that can provide the image XOR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [protocol used by VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol). Especially the linked papers.

You could also send the draw-commands directly to the client instead of the generated image, but that depends on your use-case.

Comment: How can I send the draw-commands directly to the client?, do you mean using the RDP?, is their any API that I redirect the draw commands?

Comment: RDP uses a custom display driver that the server renders to and instead of drawing it directly, it sends it to the client first. I'm not aware of libraries that can do that, although you might have luck installing a system (or application if that's all you need) wide hook to intercept all WM_PAINT? messages and transfer those to the client. Since those should be GDI+ commands they are easy to draw on the client side. You could have a look at [Rdesktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdesktop), a FOSS implementation of the MS RDP protocol.